# Does numpy.dot behave different from matlab .*?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I try to port matlab code to numpy, particularly a matrix multiplication:

```
 % matlab multiplication of two 480x640 double, yields 480x640 double
 result = xgrid.*depth
```

In python I thought it should be something like

```
 result = xgrid.dot(depth)
```

but I get a `ValueError: shapes (480,640) and (480,640) not aligned: 640 (dim 1) != 480 (dim 0)` Transposing does not help since it changes the shape of the output.

How could I port the code correctly?

Comment: You cannot multiply two non-square matrices of the same dimensions, but that is a mathematical "problem", and doesn't have anything to do with numpy.

Comment: Oh, sure, I was too focused on a numpy/matlab issue to see that ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The MATLAB `.*` is element by element multiplication.  In `numpy` plain `*` is the same thing. `np.dot` is the matrix multiplication function..

Answer (score 3):

The translation is, elementwise multiplication:

```
result = xgrid .* depth; % matlab
result = xgrid * depth   # python
```

and matrix multiplication:

```
result = xgrid * depth;   % matlab
result = xgrid.dot(depth) # python
```

Comment: And just to round out the comparisons, matlab's `dot(A, B)` is equivalent to numpy's `np.sum(A.conj()*B, axis=0)`

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, it looks like that, in `numpy`, you're using the [`array` class](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html). By default, the operations on objects of this class are *pointwise*:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

>>> a * a
array([[ 1,  4],
       [ 9, 16]])
```

In fact, you need to call functions to get it to be "matrix-wise":

```
>>> np.dot(a, a)
array([[ 7, 10],
       [15, 22]])
```

---

You might also be interested in checking [`numpy.matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html).

Answer (score -2):

numpy.dot is not matrix multipication, but the inner product. try numpy.multiply or numpy.outer for what you want to achieve

```
result = numpy.multiply(xgrid,depth)
```

Comment: When called on two two-dimensional arguments, `numpy.dot` *does* exactly do matrix multiplication.

Comment: inner product *is* matrix multiplication of things with singleton dimension.